# How to randomize comma separated rows to create word arrangement puzzles?

Tags: programming

I have an external file named `input.txt` consisting of comma separated rows as follows. NOTE: The rows may contain Japanese characters as well.

```
i, love, LaTeX, very, much
i, am, a, student
```

I want to create a puzzle sheet on which randomized rows are printed but each with a counting number on the left. More precisely, the words per row are randomized. No randomization among rows.

Only when the option `show-answer=true`, is the original row  displayed with red color.

## Minimal Not Working Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{input.txt}
i, love, LaTeX, very, much
i, am, a, student
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\Randomize[show-answer=true]{input.txt}
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

If `show-answer=true`, `\Randomize` produce the following

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  LaTeX, i, very, love, much \\
                \textcolor{red}{i, love, LaTeX, very, much}
    \item i, student, a, am \\
                \textcolor{red}{i, am, a, student}
\end{enumerate}
```

If `show-answer=false`, `\Randomize` produces the following

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  LaTeX, i, very, love, much 
    \item i, student, a, am 
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}

        tp = tex.print
        local questions = {}
        local answers = {}

    function file_exists(name)
        local f=io.open(name,"r")
        if f~=nil then io.close(f) return true else return false end
        end

    function Puzzle ( name )
        local f,i,j
        if not file_exists (name)
        then
        tex.print ("Le fichier "..name.." n''existe pas")
        else
            out = io.open( name , 'r' )
            t = out:read("*all")
            io.close(out)
            --% slpit the file in lines
            for i in t:gmatch("([^\n]+)")
            do
                local line = {}
                local line_q
                --% split the lines in words
                for j in i:gmatch("([^%p]+)")
                do
                    j = j:gsub("%s","")
                    table.insert ( line , j )
                end
                --% store the answer
                table.insert ( answers , i )
                --% make and store the question
                line_q = ""
                while line[1] ~= nil
                do
                line_q = line_q
                    ..table.remove(line, math.random(1,#line))
                    ..", "
                end
                line_q = line_q:sub(1,-3)
                table.insert(questions , line_q)
            end
        end 
    end

    function Questions ( rep )
        local i,j
        tp ("\\begin{enumerate}")
            for i,j in ipairs(questions)
            do
                tp ("\\item "..j)
                if rep
                then
                    tp ("\\\\\\textcolor{red}{"..answers[i].."}")
                end
            end
        tp ("\\end{enumerate}")
    end

\end{luacode*}

\newcommand{\Questions}[1]{%
    \luadirect{
        Puzzle("#1")
        Questions()
    }
}

\newcommand{\Answers}{%
    \luadirect{
        Questions(1)
    }
}


\begin{filecontents*}{input.txt}
i, love, LaTeX, very, much
i, am, a, student
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Questions}
\Questions{input.txt}

\bigskip

\textbf{Answers}
\Answers
\end{document}
```